# How can I remove line breaks from H tags in Drupal 7?

Tags: css, drupal, tags

I've tried all of the obvious settings for h2 with no success - I still get the line break!

These are the CSS settings I've tried without success:

```
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Any other solutions?  Thanks!

Comment: `display: inline` should work. Can you check in your browser's CSS inspector whether there are any other rules overwriting this?

Comment: How are you creating this `h2`? What do you mean by "line break"? Is there a line break within the element, or do you want the header to appear inline with other elements? I'm only using Drupal 6, but the 'line break converter' for the 'Full HTML' input format has bitten me on multiple occasions, creating `<br>`s where I didn't want them.

Comment: Pekka - there aren't any rules overwriting my settings - you can see what I'm talking about here - http://cmc.infinitymark.com/advantages-using-cmc

Comment: Solution ended up being the input format setting - what sucks is that now I have to put <br>'s in place wherever I want line breaks - oh well.  Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: inline` for the h tag, and make sure that the consecutive element is also an inline element (i.e. a `span`, not a `p`).

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dDAzm/)